# How to save language skill levels correctly in a database

Tags: mysql

I think I am before a problem where many of you were before. I have a registration form where a user can pick any language of the planet and then pick his skill level for the respective language from a *selectbox*.

So, for example:

```
Language1: German
Skill: Fluent
Language2: English
Skill: Basic
```

I'm thinking what's the best way to store these values in a MySQL database.

I thought of two ways.
First way: creating a column for each language and assigning a skill value to it.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| UserID |   language_en    |  language_ge       |
--------------------------------------------------
|   22   |       1          |         4          |
--------------------------------------------------
|   23   |       3          |         4          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So the language is always the column's name and the number represents the skill level (1. Basic, 2. Average ... )

I believe this is a nice way to work with these things and it is also pretty fast. The problem starts when there are 50 languages or more. It doesn't sound like a good idea to make 50 columns where the script always have to check them all if a user have any skill in that language.

Second way: inserting an array in one of the table's column. The table will look like this:

```
----------------------------------
| UserID |       languages       |  
----------------------------------
|   22   | "ge"=>"4", "en"=>"1"  |   
----------------------------------
```

This way the user with ID 22 has skill level 4 for Germany and skill level 1 for English. This is fine because we don't need to check 50 additional columns (or even more) but it's not the right way in my eyes anyway.
We have to parse a lot of results and find a user with, for example, has level 1 for Germany and level 2 for Spanish without looking for the English skill level - it will take the server's a longer time and when bigger data comes we are in trouble.

I bet many of you have experienced this kind of issue. Please, can someone advise me how to sort this out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: but the second one in not good from business use case.What will you do if you want to find users who have 4 in English or any language?

Comment: @Amar I 100% agree with you, both of my examples are not best when you have a lot of languages. I just can't figurate how else can I do it

Comment: I agree with Amar, it makes your SQL queries much harder if you use that kind of array to 1 column (using MySQL `LIKE` is much heavier than fetching data directly from independent columns), unless you're planning always to rely in fetching and searching that array manually...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd advise you to have a separate table with all the languages:

```
Table: Language
+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| LanguageID | LanguageNameShort | LanguageName |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|          1 | en                | English      |
|          2 | de                | German       |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

And another table to link the users to the languages:

```
Table: LanguageLink
+--------+------------+--------------+
| UserID | LanguageID | SkillLevelID |
+--------+------------+--------------+
|     22 |          1 |            1 |
|     22 |          2 |            4 |
|     23 |          1 |            3 |
|     23 |          2 |            4 |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

This is the normalised way to represent that kind of relations in a DB. All data is easily searchable and you don't have to change the DB scheme if you add a language.

To render a user's languages you could use a query like that. It will give you a row per lanugage a user speaks:

```
SELECT
    LanguageLink.UserID,
    LanguageLink.SkillLevelID,
    Language.LanguageNameShort
FROM
    LanguageLink,
    Language
WHERE
    LanguageLink.UserID = 22
    AND LanguageLink.LanguageID = Language.LanguageID
```

If you want to go further, you could create another table fo the skill level:

```
Table: Skill
+--------------+-----------+
| SkillLevelID | SkillName |
+--------------+-----------+
|            1 | bad       |
|            2 | mediocre  |
|            3 | good      |
|            4 | perfect   |
+--------------+-----------+
```

What I've done here is called [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). I'd recommend reading about it, it may help you design further databases.

Comment: Seems a consistent solution, it solves the problem of creating independent columns for each language. The Language table can even be divided by language code and language "names". There can also be a 3rd table mapping skill levels (ids) with skill "names" and/or descriptions.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Beat,  this is much better solution then any of that I present.  I just want to ask if there is not going to be a problem with big if / else statement before render it on site.

Or how it should looks like? I can imagine userID is foreign key so this is how I pair it with table "users" But how will I pair it with table "languages"

Can I ask you to create simple MYSQL Statment example  with 3 tables: users, languages, user_languages?

Comment: @Andurit your user_languages table is Beat's second table, with a FKey to the user table (userid) and another to the language table (languageid). You can get the create SQL statements by creating these tables and exporting them through http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ (if you're using a local environment), actually it's faster to do it that way and you won't have to check the syntax).
@ Beat glad it was useful :)

Comment: @Andurit I've included an example query

Comment: Thanks Beat, answer marked as correct. I appreciate your help